# How to save string by using button

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to learn android programming , and I am making contact list.
I already made Contact input and I am trying to save it on the next "page" , so when the user press "Save Contact" button , it will save contact and when the user checks list , he will do it by pressing "Contact List" button , how do to that ?
I am only into few hours of programming , 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, Admir, to the StackOverflow. You may find useful to read this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - then to edit your question accordingly. Thus you will get more relevant answer and your question will be more useful for other readers, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to store data in android

1. Shared preferences
2. Saving to SQLite database
3. Writing to local storage (as a file)

Following link in android developer website will give you more explanation in each data storing method

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html